# Prob. 10, sec. 3.1 in Kreyszig "introductory Functional Analysis with Applications"

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ denote complex numbers. Show that $\langle{u,v} \rangle=z_{1}\bar z_{2}$ defines an inner product, which yields the usual metric on the complex plane. Under what condition do we have orthogonality?

I like that, but I do not know if it is correct

1) $\langle{z_{1}+z_{2},z_{3}\rangle} = (z_{1}+z_{2})\bar z_{3}$ = $z_{1} \bar z_{3}+z_{2} \bar z_{3}= \langle z_{1},z_{3} \rangle + \langle z_{1},z_{3} \rangle$

2) $ \langle \alpha z_{1},z_{2} \rangle = \alpha (z_{1}) \bar z_{2}= \alpha (z_{1} \bar z_{2}) = \alpha \langle{z_{1},z_{2}\rangle}$

3) $ \langle z_{1},z_{2} \rangle = z_{1}\bar z_{2} = \bar z_{2}z_{1} = \overline{z_{2}\bar z_{1}} = \overline{\langle z_{2}, z_{1}\rangle}$

4) $ \langle z_{1},z_{1} \rangle = z_{1}\bar z_{1} = |z_1|^2 \geq 0 $

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?  You should include the textbook's definition of $\langle u,v \rangle$ in this context, since most of us don't have access to the textbook you're using.

Comment: The textbook should have a definition of the inner product written out.  Have you tried to show that these properties hold?  If so, then where is it in the process that you get stuck?

Comment: just a minute to post the resolution did!

Comment: I'm not sure what that sentence is supposed to mean

Answer (score 1):

Your solution, as it is currently written, is complete and correct.